# Data is not pushed in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got data from API and tried to push it in an array, but when I print it, it's empty. The data is JSON.

````
fetch("url")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => sohawnID.push(data.id))
        console.log(sohawnID)

//output: []```
````

Answer (score 0):

this is because synchronous behavior of node js. what you need is to put you api call method inside a Promise function and then call it using async await. By this way program 1st wait for api response and then push data to your array

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prints empty is `console.log(sohawnID)` called before the promise fulfil meaning you are trying to print result before it arrives. You can do this:

```
fetch("url")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
               sohawnID.push(data.id);
               console.log(sohawnID)
})
        
``
```